# How to show individual summation terms when calculating sum with maxima or wxmaxima

Tags: maxima-software

I have a question about using maxima. Supposing I have the following sum:

sum (i^2, i, 0, n);

```
\[\sum_{i=0}^{n}{i}^{2}\]
```

and say I use it to sum up to 4:

sum (i^2, i, 0, 4);

= 61

If I want to list all the sum terms

1 + 4 + 9 + 16

how can I do this?

Comment: If you just want the list of numbers, you can `makelist(i^2,i,0,4)`.

Comment: that's a good work around. But the example I used was simple I need this for more complex double summations to check I've got the notation right. Maybe this still can be done with makelist() I'll investigate.

Comment: If you want to inspect a two dimension slice of numbers, you can define a formula for the $(i,j)-$entry and then use `genmatrix` to generate a matrix on screen.
e.g

$$
\begin{array}{lc}
\verb/M[i,j] := i^2 + j^2;/\\
\verb/genmatrix(M,3,3);/
\end{array}
\quad\text{ returns }\;
\begin{bmatrix}2 & 5 & 10\\5 & 8 & 13\\10 & 13 & 18\end{bmatrix}
\;\text{ on screen. }
$$

Comment: okay this is good for double sums that have conditions that form same lenght rows or column numbers but not for conditions that produce varying lenghts unfortunately.